# iOS : Add Picker Ui element dynamically

Tags: ios, uiview, picker

I am new to iOs and trying to add the picker UI element dynamically to the UI.
In the class - UIPickerView , i don't see any methods for adding the picker to the view.
Has anyone tried doing this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean you wanna change content of pickerview Dynamically ?

Comment: One and best Ever http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

Comment: what about `[self.view addSubview:picker];` ? There are several ways to integrate Picker to view.

Answer (score 0):

As with other you need to alloc+initWithFrame.

```
UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 0, 0)];
```

Then add it to your target view.

```
[yourView addSubview:pickerView];
```

Also you need to set it delegate and datasource, which will show all your elements in the picker view.

```
pickerView.dataSource=self;
pickerView.delegate=self;
```

And all other customization as :

```
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator=YES;
```

---

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
  return [array objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You adding the picker to the view just like and UIView you want to add -> addSubview method.

```
UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,320,200,)]];
pickerView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:pickerView];
```

Don't forget to set it's delegate and implement it in order to achieve it's functionality.

Answer (score 0):

> i don't see any methods for adding the picker to the view

A UIPickerView is a subclass of UIView, so you use the same methods that you'd use to add any subview to a view, namely `-addSubview:`, like this:

```
UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:theFrame];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:picker];
```

I'm assuming here that the code is in a view controller that's acting as both the delegate and data source for the picker.

Answer (score 0):

First alloc memory to your picker view.

```
UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 265, 320, 216)];
```

and then set delegate and datasource.

```
pickerView.dataSource=self;
pickerView.delegate=self;
```

after that add picker view to your main view.

```
[self.view addSubview:pickerView];
```

after that you should implement pickerview's method .

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{    
     return [array count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
        return [array objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

i hope this will work fine.